# geodesic flow and the vector field on $TM$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I'm trying to understand what my teacher wrote.

> We build a vector field $\cal{X}$ on $TM$ for which the flow, called *geodesic flow*, consists in the curves $(\gamma(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))$ where $\gamma$ is a geodesic $${\cal{X}}_X=(X^1,\cdots,X^n,-\Gamma^1_{ij}X^iX^j,\cdots,-\Gamma^n_{ij}X^iX^j)$$ Then $$\frac{d\gamma^k}{dt} = X^k\\ \frac{dX^k}{dt} = -\Gamma^k_{ij}X^iX^j$$
>   is the system of equations of the flow of $\cal{X}$.

Why is that system the set of equations defining the flow of $\cal{X}$?

it is clear that the curves $(\gamma(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))$, with $\gamma$ a geodesic, satisfy the equations but how do we know that no other curve on $TM$ satisfies these equations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x^i$ and $v^j$ form a coordinate basis for $TM$, where $M$ is a Riemannian manifold with metric tensor $g$.
Consider the vector field on $TM$ given by: 
$$\mathcal{X} = (v^1,\ldots,v^n,- \Gamma_{jk}^1v^jv^k,\ldots,-\Gamma_{jk}^nv^jv^k) 
= v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} - \Gamma_{jk}^iv^jv^k\frac{\partial}{\partial v^i} $$

*(1) What is the flow of this field?*

Well, the "flow" of any field is simply given by the dynamical system defined by following (or integrating along that field) for some time $t$. 
Consider the part of the flow on $M$ (i.e. look at the first $n$ components of $\mathcal{X}$, which determine how a point on the manifold $M$ moves. 
Consider a curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$, following this part of the field: at every point, the tangent vector to the curve is given by $v$. Thus:
$$
\frac{\partial \gamma^i}{\partial t} = v^i
$$
But then the tangent vector of the curve also needs to follow the flow prescribed by the second half of the field (i.e. the part in $T_pM$). This constrains the rate of change of the tangent vector to $\gamma$, i.e. $\partial_t \gamma^i$. But we just saw this is equal to $v^i$. So we are constraining the tangent vector to $v^i$ over time. The rate of change of $\partial_t \gamma^i$ must follow the last $n$ components of $\mathcal{X}$. Thus:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \gamma^i}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial v^i}{\partial t}
= - \Gamma_{jk}^iv^jv^k
$$

*(2) How does show the geodesic is unique?*

As the comment suggests, use the [Picard-Lindelof theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).
You have an ODE $\dot{v}^i=- \Gamma_{jk}^iv^jv^k$, which assuming a little smoothness can be uniquely solved. Then you have another ODE $\dot{\gamma}^i=v^i$ that may be uniquely solved for the same reason.

---

Related: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195656/what-exactly-is-the-geodesic-flow) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394001/hamiltonian-for-geodesic-flow?rq=1). (Also, sort of related: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/riemannian-metric-of-the-tangent-bundle?rq=1))

---

Aside: we can see why this generates geodesics by recalling the [classical geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry):
$$
\underbrace{
\frac{\partial^2\gamma^i}{\partial t^2} 
}_{\displaystyle \dot{v}^i}
+ \Gamma_{\mu\eta}^i
\underbrace{
\frac{\partial \gamma^\mu}{\partial t}
}_{\displaystyle {v}^\mu}
\underbrace{
\frac{\partial \gamma^\eta}{\partial t}}_{\displaystyle {v}^\eta}
= 0
$$
$$
\dot{v}^i = \frac{\partial v^i}{\partial t}= -\Gamma_{\mu\eta}^i{v}^\eta{v}^\mu
$$